# How do I concatenate a list of lists in C++?`

Tags: c++, list

In C++, how do I merge all the Lists stored within a main List (List) into one single List? In this case, each list simply contains ints.

Comment: Depends on the lists (the answer is as clear as the question is).

Comment: They're all just simple lists full of ints.

Comment: What type of lists - `std::list`, some custom `List` class, something else? Also, what is "a main List(List)"? Do you talk about flattening lists?

Comment: Yeah these are just std::lists and work like vectors. By "main list" I mean merge everything in the List that contains all the other lists into a single list of all the ints from each of the smaller lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using C++11 and `std::list`, and that your lists are not sorted, and that you do not care about duplicates:

```
std::list<std::list<int>> all_lists;

... //fill it somehow

std::list<int> merged;
for (const auto& l : all_lists) {
  merged.insert(merged.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
}
```

If you do not need to use your original lists anymore, you can use `std::list::splice` instead of `std::list::insert`. In that case, the syntax is:

```
 for (auto& l : all_lists) {
  merged.splice(merged.end(), l, l.begin(), l.end());
}
```

Comment: There is also `std::list::splice`, but with slightly different semantics.

Comment: Better use the versions of `splice` without a final iterator, for a constant complexity instead of a linear one.